# Get double quotes for the searchTerms result query in the URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var searchTerms = escape(jQuery('input#q').val());
var st = searchTerms.trim();
var res = st.replaceAll("TITLE","ti").replaceAll("%20","%20and%20").replaceAll("AUTHOR","au");
```

I have the above code and need the search term values in double quotes as the result
It gives result URL as : `'&query=heartmate%20and%20owens'`

But I need it as : `'&query="heartmate"%20and%20"owens"'`

Comment: Can you not `st.map(term => { return '"' + term + '"' });`?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to map the values to new values before you inject them into the request. But first you need to split the string into its individual terms...

```
let terms = st.split(' ');
```

that will return an array of the individual elements of the string, split on a space character,
then you can trim and append the term...

```
terms.map(term => { 
  term.trim(); // <-- this removes all of the whitespace characters, including 
               // space, tab, no-break space, and all the line terminator 
               // characters, including LF, CR, etc. from the beginning and end 
               // of the string
  return '"' + term + '"';
});
```

You may find the need to check a condition of `term` before applying the `map`, it really depends on what you're doing.

Comment: It says map is not a function

Comment: Oops, yeah that's only for arrays, for some reason I thought it was already one. you could `let terms = st.split(' ')` that will split the string into an array omitting the spaces between. Then you can use the `.map` function on it. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use backslash `\` to escape your character

```js
var test = " \" \" ";

console.log(test);
```